# Flutter - Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.xxx.yourApp' were found

Tags: ios, iphone, compiler-errors, flutter

After IntelliJ CE version upgrade I started getting errors during Flutter projects compilation.

`Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.xxx.yourApp' were found`

Full error stack:

```
  Flutter
  Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.xxx.yourApp' were found


  === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
  Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.xxx.yourApp' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.xxx.yourApp'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
  The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
  The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
  Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
  Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
  Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
  Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

  Error launching application on iPhone
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 20):

Remember that there is link to an XCode iOS project inside of your IntelliJ Flutter project.

To Resolve the issue open the inner iOS project in XCode:

`yourApp/iOS`

try to **compile and run** the projec in XCode
and then return to IntteliJ to run it again.

Signing settings are under General -> Signing

Refer to this issue for more [info](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10446)

Comment: Solved for me! Thank you! When I do this one time. Then no need to Xcode, Just only Android Studio can launch my flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue and realized that my Bundle ID on App Store Connect was not the same as in my "Signing and Capabilities" tab within Xcode.

For the same issue, I was also given an "An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value" error before the "no profiles for ..." error. Fixing the Bundle ID mismatch fixed both errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because permissions because I was running a project from downloads folder and XCode didn't has permissions to this folder.

To solve it:

1. Copy the project route from the error log on your editor.
2. Open the project from XCode and give the permissions when prompt
3. Then open the project with your editor and should be fine.